# Managing MSP Tenants for Anti-Phishing Controls

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365, phishing

I'm trying to find a simple way to report on our tenants' settings regarding Microsoft's recently introduced Anti-Phishing controls.

If possible, I'm looking to find an easy GUI method to report on these, with any management considered a very happy bonus. Otherwise I'll just use the cmdlet that they detail in their docs on a '`Get-AntiPhishPolicy`' and (where necessary) '`Set-AntiPhishPolicy`' basis.

FWIW

- I've searched "phishing", "outlook phishing", and a couple more, here.
- I've trawled the admin screens (at single tenant level), and couldn't find anything useful.
- I've performed a couple of deep Googles (I like to "intitle")

If anyone can help, I'd be most obliged, otherwise I guess we'll just have to roll up our sleeves and manually go through each tenant. :-)

Best
Eliot

Answer (score 0):

Do you want wo know” Set up Office 365 ATP anti-phishing and anti-phishing policies”?
https://msexperttalk.com/setting-office-365-anti-phishing-policies/

Comment: Hi, Jayce, unfortunately, that's not very helpful. I hoped that my question was pretty clear ... but I'll break it down.  
  
1. I'd like to report on some data.  <br/>
2. The data that I need to report on is set on each of the tenants that I manage.  
3. The specific setting that I would like to know the value of is the new Anti-Phishing Policy from Microsoft. Which you have linked to setting up, not reporting on.  

Hope that this aides your understanding, but, sorry, your response is quite far away from what I was looking asking. Thanks for trying, though. :-)

Comment: You may need to open a service request for Office 365 backend team.

Comment: Cheers, @jayce, seems that way, eh? Not to worry. Sorry about the lack of carriage returns ... really struggling with 'cemments' formatting!